# I could not able to install PyTorch on raspberry is there a PyTorch version which can be installed on raspberry pi 3b+?

Tags: python, pytorch, openai-whisper

I could not able to install PyTorch on raspberry is there a PyTorch version which can be installed on raspberry pi 3b+?

I tried diffrent version and none worked for me

I tried official sites other installation guides and nothing worked for me with error ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Comment: Have you looked at this link? https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-pytorch/  As per that page: "The only requirement of running Pytorch on your device is that you must be running a 64-bit operating system." I suspect the OS on your RPi 3 is 32 bit.